# Как сделать необязательный символ в паттерне?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть паттерн номера телефона

```
<input pattern="([+][0-9][(][0-9]{3}[)][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2})">
```

Как сделать так, чтобы + был опциональным?

Причиной такому действию служит, что юзер может ввести 2 формата телефона =

8(832)424-32-42
или
+7(832)424-32-42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\+?
```

Вопросительный знак означает, что предшествующий ему символ должен встречаться 1 или 0 раз. Слэш превращает оператор "+", означающий 1 или больше, в обычный символ `+`.

Или так

```
\+{0,1}
```

Comment: Не помогло, я так пробовал

Comment: Значит пробовал не так. Как именно ?

Comment: ([+?][0-9][(][0-9]{3}[)][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2})

Comment: Так я и думал :) Квадратные скобки то вокруг этого надо убрать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийВенеград И экранировать символ, `\+?`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME блин, точно. Плюс же тоже квантифаер!